# Fix alignment in nested description list without line break

Tags: horizontal-alignment, description, nesting

I'm trying to make a nested description list like so:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[Languages:]
\begin{description}
    \item[High:]Python, Java, R, SQL, SAS
    \item[Intermediate:]HTML5, CSS, JavaScript, C++
    \item[Basic:] \LaTeX, Batch, Shell, Powershell, MongoDB
\end{description}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

And my output looks like this:
[image: Misaligned nested description]

I'd like the **High**, **Intermediate**, and **Basic** to be horizontally aligned. I've messed with the `enumitem` package and parameters such as `labelindent`, `align`, `leftmargin`, `itemindent`, and a few others to no avail. Could anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean *vertically* aligned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[Languages:]\begin{minipage}[t][][t]{12cm}
\begin{description}
    \item[High:]Python, Java, R, SQL, SAS
    \item[Intermediate:]HTML5, CSS, JavaScript, C++
    \item[Basic:] \LaTeX, Batch, Shell, Powershell, MongoDB
\end{description}
\end{minipage}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The title of the questions says "without line break".

Comment: This breaks it to a new line. I'd like to keep **High** on the same line as **Languages:**, and align the rest with **High** going down.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks! I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I think the minipage is the best way to go. Thanks!

Comment: Hpwever there's a drawback: a minipage can't break across pages.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the leftmargin large enough:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,calc}
\begin{document}
blblblb \\
blblblb
\begin{description}[leftmargin=\widthof{Languages:xxx},labelwidth=!]
\item[Languages:]
\begin{description}
    \item[High:]Python, Java, R, SQL, SAS
    \item[Intermediate:]HTML5, CSS, JavaScript, C++
    \item[Basic:] \LaTeX, Batch, Shell, Powershell, MongoDB
\end{description}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works well, but I have other things in the outer description list, which this messes up the alignment for.

Answer (score 2):

*Discalimer:* I didn't notice the `without line break`, sorry. I read the question but not the title :P

You can trick the `description` giving it an invisible character:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[Languages:]\mbox{}
\begin{description}
    \item[High:]Python, Java, R, SQL, SAS
    \item[Intermediate:]HTML5, CSS, JavaScript, C++
    \item[Basic:] \LaTeX, Batch, Shell, Powershell, MongoDB
\end{description}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Why not a simple `\mbox{}` or `\leavevmode`?

Comment: Apparently because I like to make things more complicated than necessary :P Thanks!

Comment: thanks, this wasn't what the OP wanted but it *was* what I wanted ...